# Is multithreading in C++ better supported by Visual Studio compared to GCC?

Tags: visual-studio, compilation

Is multithreading in C++ better supported by Visual Studio compared to GCC? For example, the code in comment does not produce race conditions when compiled with Visual Studio, but when compiled with GCC, race condition occurs on multiple occasions.

Comment: Of code has race conditions it most likely has them anywhere. Compiler doesn’t really matter. But there’s no code here...

Comment: Code with race conditions is broken. "But it works in Visual Studio". Learn what [undefined behaviour](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means.